# How to properly navigate a list of objects as the UI changes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom control containing a TreeView, a Toolstrip with a few buttons, and a Textbox.

Then I have a class `Issue` with a few `string` and `bool` properties (most importantly `string ID` and `string[] files`) as well as a `Projects` class which contains 2 `List<Issue>`, some other properties, and a few methods for interacting with the list.

The `TreeView` displays `Project.ID` as 'parent' nodes and `Issue.ID` as 'child' nodes. The `Textbox` displays the `files` property of the currently selected `Issue` child node.

I don't really know how I should approach navigating my `Project.IssueList1` and `Project.IssueList2` whilereading / writing data back to it as the user selects different items in the `TreeView`.

Currently, in the `TreeView_AfterSelect` event I find the `Issue` in the list and set `textbox1.Lines = issue.files` then in the `Textbox_TextChanged` event I assign the `Lines` value back to `issue.files`. This is functional, everything works, but I don't like it. It feels sloppy and "hacky".

99.9% of the time, the user is copy-pasting one or more filepaths into the UI, so it's not like the event triggers every single time they're typing something out, but I still don't like this approach.

Is there a way to bind the controls to the objects and have the framework kind of take care of traversing the list and updating the UI? I guess that's the purpose of an ORM, but I wasn't sure if there was anything similar built in.

Comment: I think that a textbox might be the wrong usercontrol for your `string[] files` . One way would be to use a `BindingList<string>` for the files and a `Listbox` as control, then set the `BindingList` as `Datasource` for the `Listbox`.

Comment: I'll have to look at the `BindingList`, I'm not familiar with that object. I just went with the `Textbox` as it seemed to be the easiest, most "free form" form of data entry. The general use of the application is simply copying the list of files from SVN commit logs and pasting it into the application, as part of an update deploying utility.

Comment: It seems the post answers your question and it would be great if you mark it as accepted and vote for it :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei sorry! Got disctracted and forgot to come back and accept it

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete solution that I've implemented and hope to be useful for you.

This solution is based on using `BindingSource` and its `DataSource` and `DataMember` properties to create a master-detail databiinding and.

Here is steps:

**1- Define your Classes**

```
public class Project
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
}

public class Issue
{
    public string IssueId { get; set; }
    public List<IssueFile> Files { get; set; }
}

public class IssueFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**2- Create a Form**
Create a form with this design:

- Put a `TreeView`
- Put a `BindingSource` with `Name` set to `projectBindingSource`
- Put a `BindingSource` with `Name` set to `issuesBindingSource`, and `DataSource` set to `projectBindingSource`, and `DataMember` set to `Issues`
- Put a `BindingSource` with `Name` set to `filesBindingSource`, `DataSource` set to `issuesBindingSource`, `DataMember` set to `Files`
- Put a `DataGridView` with `DataSource` set to `filesBindingSource`
- Put a `TextBox` which in `(DataBindings)` set its `Text` bind to `issuesBindingSource - IssueId`

[image]

**3- Load data to tree and perform data binding**

Load data to your data sources and tree:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var projects= new List<Project>();

    //get data of projects from whenever you want and fill the list

    this.projectBindingSource.DataSource = projects;
    projects.ToList().ForEach(p =>
    {
        var projectNode = new TreeNode(p.Id);
        //Put project in tag of project node
        projectNode.Tag = p;
        p.Issues.ToList().ForEach(i =>
            {
                var issueNode = new TreeNode(i.IssueId);
                //Put issue in tag of issue node
                issueNode.Tag = i;
                projectNode.Nodes.Add(issueNode);
            });
        this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(projectNode);
    });
}
```

**4- Handle AfterSelect event of tree**
Handle `AfterSelect` event of tree and if selected node is an issue node, set current items of your binding sources:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Parent != null)
    {
        var project = e.Node.Parent.Tag as Project;
        this.projectBindingSource.Position = this.projectBindingSource.IndexOf(project);

        var issue = e.Node.Tag as Issue;
        this.issuesBindingSource.Position = this.issuesBindingSource.IndexOf(issue);
    }
}
```

**5-Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Quite the lengthy post. It'll take a little bit before I get to actually test this route as a have a few more things I need to take care of first, but thanks again.