# How to use a DataGridView to display data from the registry

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to use `DataGridView` basically as a fancy list control, where some columns use checkboxes and others allow selecting a value from a drop-down list of possible values.

I want to populate the view from registry key values e.g. the user selects the registry key, and values from that key are used to add rows to the view following some bespoke logic. As the user changes values in the Cells, these should cause the registry to be updated.

I believe an unbound approach (no dataset) is the best option here, manually adding rows and adding on-change event handlers to each cell. But I wanted to check this makes sense, and I'm not trying to force my C++ view of things on to the more sophisticated .NET data-binding approach - am I doing this in a reasonable manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know `DataGridView` can be bound to a `List` of your business objects well and you don't need `DataSet` and `DataTable` for all cases.

So you can use both bound or unbound solution with / without using `DataSet` and `DataTable`.

Its enough to create a class as model of your data that you want to show in `DataGridView`, and then shape your data to `List<YourModelClass>` and then set the result list it as `DataSource` of `DataGridView`, or simply add each item to `Rows` collection of `DataGridView`.

I recommend using a data bound approach:

- This way changes on your models will be directly done on your models and there is no need to read your data from `DataGridView` back to your model.
- Also you can implement 2-way data binding to reflect changes of your models in your UI automatically.

**As a simple example:**

Define your model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    public bool Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Provide data and bind data:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<MyModel>();
    list.Add(new MyModel() { Property1 = "Value 1", Property2 = 1, Property3 = false });
    list.Add(new MyModel() { Property1 = "Value 2", Property2 = 2, Property3 = true });
    list.Add(new MyModel() { Property1 = "Value 3", Property2 = 3, Property3 = true });

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}
```

and run program:

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Boy You are welcome:) I added a simple example for you. It is the most simple case. you can setup your datagridview 's columns and any thing you can do in bound approach.

Comment: @Mr.Boy You may find my other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32484870/3110834) helpful, the answer contains complex master-detail databinding to business objects using treeview and datagridview.